# Printing a linked List only prints most recent data entry in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm printing a linked list after each addition to it. The problem is that it only prints the most recently added node. The user is supposed to enter a string which is used to make a node and then that node is added to the list. Here is the code:

```
int main() {
    char userChoice = printMenu();
    int setNumber;

    while (userChoice != 'q') {
        printf("set: ");
        scanf("%d", &setNumber);

        Node **nodeArray;
        nodeArray = malloc(10 * sizeof(Node *));

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            nodeArray[i] = malloc(sizeof(Node));    
        }

        if (userChoice == 'a') 
            add(&nodeArray, setNumber);
        else 
            printf("Please enter a valid menu option.");

        //printf("%s\n", (nodeArray[setNumber]->next)->data);

        userChoice = printMenu();
    }

void add(Node ***nodeArray, int setNumber) {
        char userString[5];
        printf("Please enter some data: ");
        scanf("%s", userString);

        Node *head = *nodeArray[setNumber];     /* head pointer to first element of array (dummy) */
        Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));   /* new node to be added to array */

        strncpy(newNode->data, userString, sizeof(newNode->data));  /* copies string entered by the user to data field of new node */
        newNode->next = NULL;   /* initializes next field of new node to NULL */

        while (head->next) 
            head = head->next;      /* points head to next element in list */
        head->next = newNode;   /* adds element to list */

        head = *nodeArray[setNumber];   /* points head back to start of list */
        Node *tmp = head;       

        printf("List is: ");
        while (tmp->next) {
            printf("%s", tmp->data);
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
}
```

Just as an example, when I enter "one", it prints out "one". Then when I add "two" it only prints out two instead of printing out "one two". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that a new block of memory is being created every time you enter into the loop. Cut and paste the code that creates the array outside of the loop and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

This `*nodeArray[setNumber]` means `*(nodeArray[setNumber])` but you seem to mean `(*nodeArray)[setNumber]`. Or better, don't pass `&nodeArray` to `add()`, just pass `nodeArray`. So:

```
add(nodeArray, setNumber);
...
void add(Node **nodeArray, int setNumber) {
...
Node *head = nodeArray[setNumber];
```

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, but would you mind elaborating a little bit? I'm new to C...and not very good at it....

Comment: It's a little confusing to talk about what's going on in this code because you've used the same symbol name `nodeArray` to mean two different things. In `main` it's a pointer to an array of pointers. But in `add` it's a pointer to a pointer to an array of pointers.

Comment: Well I passed the address of nodeArray, which is a pointer to an array of pointers, into add.

Comment: You'd do `add(&nodeArray)` only if you need `add()` to be able to make main's `nodeArray` point to a different memory location, but you don't do that.

Comment: I do need it to do that. Each pointer in the pointer array needs to be a linked list. So I want add to be able to manipulate it.

Comment: I think you don't want to modify where main's nodeArray points to. You want main's nodeArray to continue to point to the memory you malloc'ed from the heap. Instead you want to modify the pointers that are in the array that main's nodeArray points at.

Comment: Exactly! How do I do that? And will that fix my printing issue...?

Comment: Well, make the change I described above. That's a start. But it looks like your `while (tmp->next)` loop isn't quite right. I recommend drawing pictures and be sure you're clear on what pointers are pointing to what objects.

Comment: Ok I made the changes that you suggested. The printing is still an issue though. Any suggestions?